# By is not a function in selenium nightwatch

Tags: selenium, xpath, nightwatch.js

I could not use the default By commands in selenium. Below is my script

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lotstatus_q']/div/table/tbody/tr"));
```

my script is failing and the result is this:By is not a function

is there any other items that I need to install?

All other By commands are not functioning.

Comment: Did you import all selenium JARs?

Comment: Did U start wrom working example? which language of script?

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake, you cannot directly access to Selenium API from Nightwatch.js !

Nightwatch is just an override of the *WebDriver Wire Protocole* (exposed by Selenium as REST API)
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

But you can use XPath selectors with Nightwatch:

```
client.useXpath().waitForElementVisible("//*[@id='lotstatus_q']/div/table/tbody/tr")
```

Read the doc about XPath: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-xpath-selectors

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the regular Java patterns with NightWatchJS and also NightWatch Apis does not work that way...

Please see the API docs on how you can use http://nightwatchjs.org/api#commands

I think you are trying to do

```
browser.elements("css locator" , "value of your css", function (result){
     // here result is the return from calling selenium wire protocol /elements
     // Using the identifier of your CSS locators
})
```